# cxgrid footer format - sum time in HH:MM format

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

In cxgrid,I am summing time in a footer (the field in question is a Time field).
I have changed its property to TimeEdit and changed  its time display
format to  'tfHourMin'. However I can not do that to the underlying footer.
It keeps displaying hh:mm:ss. Is there a way to have the footer display also  'tfHourMin' format ???

edit : If I do this I get "Could not convert variant of type (Null) into type (Double" error

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1TcxGridDBDataControllerTcxDataSummaryFooterSummaryItems1GetText(
  Sender: TcxDataSummaryItem; const AValue: Variant; AIsFooter: Boolean;
  var AText: string);
begin
 AText := FormatDateTime('hh:mm', AValue);
end;
```

Comment: I am not using groups.

Comment: Sorry, I thought `Summary.FooterFormat` was meant to do what you need, but its purpose is different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the summary item's `OnGetText` event to provide your own text to display, something like

```
procedure TForm1.H_FormatSummaryItem(Sender: TcxDataSummaryItem; const AValue: Variant; AIsFooter: Boolean; var AText: string);
begin
  if(TVarData(AValue).VType in [varNull, varEmpty])then AText := ''
  else begin
     if((Sender as TcxGridTableSummaryItem).Kind = skSum)then begin
        AText := FormatDateTime('hh:nn', AValue);
     end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Must be the `Sender as TcxGridTableSummaryItem` statement... replace the `TcxGridTableSummaryItem` with the correct summary item type or comment the `if` part out altogether if you have attached the eventhandler only to `skSum` items.